# Срабатывание точки остановки на VS

Tags: c++, visual-c++

При выполнение кода столкнулся с проблемой: "Срабатывание точки остановки".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <ctime>

//Длина массива
int sizeArr() {
    int z;
    std::cout << "Введите длину массива: ";
    std::cin >> z;
    return z;
}

void writeArr(int z, int *x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        std::cout << x[i];
        if (i != z - 1) std::cout << ", ";
        else std::cout << "." << std::endl;
    }
}

int initilizationArr(int z, int *x) {
    //std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        x[i] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
    }
    return *x;
}

void sumArrs(int z) {
    int* arr1 = new int(z);
    *arr1 = initilizationArr(z, arr1);
    writeArr(z, arr1);
}

void clener() {

}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size = sizeArr();
    sumArrs(size);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, вместо одного `int`'а

```
int* arr1 = new int(z);
```

попробуете создать массив?

```
int* arr1 = new int[z];
```